# How to call a method for each value in a string?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
var mystring = ',32,33,34,35,36'
```

How can I call a method for each value?

Comment: Have you tried using Split?

Comment: `"1,2,3".Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().ForEach(x => DoSomething(x));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

For ex:

```
foreach (string i in mystring.split(','))
    callYourFunction(i);
```

Does this suits you?